# Mail body: & becomes (R)

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

We have a site from where we send a auto generated mail to our customer when a new customer register. our mail got a activation link which look like

> http://www.bba-reman.com/catalogue/ConfirmRegistration.aspx?email=meyer@reman.de&id=907a5253-106c-4fb3-9882-83e634e651b2

but when our german customer reveive the mail then he got the below activation link where you notice & character change to ®

> **http://www.bba-reman.com/catalogue/ConfirmRegistration.aspx?email=meyer@reman.de®id=907a5253-106c-4fb3-9882-83e634e651b2**

Can anyone tell me why & character getting change to ®?
How to resolve this kind of problem?

Comment: sounds like character encoding to me http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails

Comment: Is the mail body in html format? try replacing & with:- **&amp;**

Answer (score 1):

try using `CreateAlternateViewFromString` property, here is the example code

```
MailMessage emailmsg = new MailMessage("from@address.co.za", "to@address.co.za")
emailmsg.Subject = "Subject";
emailmsg.IsBodyHtml = false;
emailmsg.ReplyToList.Add("from@address.co.za");
emailmsg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
emailmsg.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
emailmsg.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
emailmsg.Body = null;

var plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(EmailBody, emailmsg.BodyEncoding, "text/plain");
plainView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
emailmsg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);

SmtpClient sSmtp = new SmtpClient();
sSmtp.Send(emailmsg);
```

Comment: what CreateAlternateViewFromString does ? can u plzz explain how i could be benefited just following your code?

Comment: @Thomas: Did you try `AlternateViews` as shows in above example?